# How to check the size of the column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I want to calculate how much data we are storing on each column per row key.

I want to check the size of the column and number of keys/rows. Can any one help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

[cfstats](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCFstats.html) will give you an estimated number of keys, and [cfhistograms](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCFhisto.html) will tell you the number of columns/cells and size of a row/partition (Look for "Row/partition Size" and "Column/Cell Count")

Comment: I think the data in cassandra will be compressed using snappy. Do you know how to calculate the exact size of the file coming from application( I mean without compression). If it is doing the compression then how much size it is saving?

Comment: Cfstats has "SSTable compression ratio" statistic.

Comment: The SSTable Compression Ratio value is 0.17811851098373616. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that the compressed data file is 0.178 the size of the uncompressed data.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on the accuracy required.  The histograms from jmx are estimates that could give you a rough idea of what the data looks like.  A map reduce job might be the best way to calculate exact column sizes.

What I would recommend is when you insert your column you also insert the size of the data you are storing in another CF/column.  Then depending on how you store it (which you would change based on how you want to query it) you could do things like find the largest columns and such.